# How to exclude a directory when zipping files

Tags: zip, cygwin

I'm trying to exclude a certain directory when building an archive using `zip`. Here's what I have tried:

```
$ zip home.zip -y -r HOME -x '/AppData' -x '/AppData*' -x '/AppData/*' -x 'AppData' -x 'AppData*' -x 'AppData/*'
```

Produces:

```
  adding: HOME/ (stored 0%)
  adding: HOME/AppData/ (stored 0%)
  adding: HOME/AppData/a (deflated 39%)
  adding: HOME/AppData/LocalLow/ (stored 0%)
  adding: HOME/AppData/LocalLow/Sun/ (stored 0%)
  adding: HOME/AppData/LocalLow/Sun/Java/ (stored 0%)
  adding: HOME/AppData/LocalLow/Sun/Java/a (deflated 39%)
  adding: HOME/AppData/LocalLow/Sun/Java/Deployment/ (stored 0%)
  adding: HOME/AppData/LocalLow/Sun/Java/Deployment/a (deflated 39%)
```

My directory tree looks like:

```
./HOME
./HOME/AppData
./HOME/AppData/a
./HOME/AppData/LocalLow
./HOME/AppData/LocalLow/Sun
./HOME/AppData/LocalLow/Sun/Java
./HOME/AppData/LocalLow/Sun/Java/a
./HOME/AppData/LocalLow/Sun/Java/Deployment
./HOME/AppData/LocalLow/Sun/Java/Deployment/a
```

So it seems to be ignoring my `-x` options.

**What is the correct syntax for the `-x` option?**

Found [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6540/excluding-a-directory-when-zipping-files) but as you can see above, it didn't solve my problem.

I am using Info-ZIP 3.0 on Cygwin 1.7.35 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```bsh
-x */AppData/*
# or
--exclude */AppData/*
```

Don't forget to add the first slash, because otherwise it also matches any paths that has "AppData" in it, not just specifically the path that starts with "AppData".

Answer (score 8):

Try putting it as `-x '*AppData/*'`

Comment: Yes, that does work, but it also matches **any** paths that has "AppData" in it, not just specifically the path that starts with "AppData".

Comment: In that case using absolute paths will work

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you mean by an absolute path?

Comment: @GreenGiant Absolute pathname is a pathname that begins with a slash. Absolute is for example `/home/user`, relative when PWD is `/home` is `user`.

Comment: Ok. I guess what I want is a relative path, so that my command doesn't have to change based on what the current directory is.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the path that `zip` is matching against includes the root path element you give it, unless the root is `.`

In my case, if I wanted to exclude anything under `LocalLow`, I needed:

```
$ zip home.zip -y -r HOME -x 'HOME/AppData/LocalLow/*'
```

Yielding:

```
  adding: HOME/ (stored 0%)
  adding: HOME/AppData/ (stored 0%)
  adding: HOME/AppData/a (deflated 39%)
```

If you instead `cd` into the `HOME` directory and use `.` as the root, you don't need to specify the root element in the exclude path:

```
$ cd HOME
$ zip home.zip -y -r . -x 'AppData/LocalLow/*'

  adding: AppData/ (stored 0%)
  adding: AppData/a (deflated 39%)
```